# How to apply Fast Folding algorithm?

Tags: radio-astronomy, data-analysis, algorithm

I have [High Time Resolution Universe](https://www.mpifr-bonn.mpg.de/research/fundamental/htru) dataset. I have applied de-dispersion on this HTRU dataset, and thereafter I applied the folding function to fold the dataset.

How I can find that the periodicity of the signal using a fast-folding[image] algorithm?

Comment: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/HTRU2 . i am using this dataset for finding the pulsar.

Comment: Meta discussion: https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/534/6

Comment: can anyone help me?

Comment: IMO it belongs to Computational Science subforum.

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "de-dispersion" and "the folding function" and "fast folding algorithm". None of these things are obvious.

Comment: @RobJeffries De-dispersion is describe here, and it seems to be the appropriate subject matter: http://www.jb.man.ac.uk/distance/frontiers/pulsars/section4.html

Comment: @RobJeffries Fast Folding algorithm is described here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.05581

Comment: "Folding function" does seem to be context-dependent, but maybe the above two pieces of info will help ascertain that.

Comment: @user28958 The bounty I put on your question just expired. If you found the solution to this on your own, you can add your own answer to help out the next person who has this problem.